# How should I avoid crash while using wxWebView

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I am using `wxWebView` in my wxWidgets app, to display webview of my website(`Okta login page`) for login. 
I am using following syntax:

```
m_browser = wxWebView::New(m_temppanel, wxID_MyLoginWebView, redirectUrl, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(450, 600));

m_browser->Connect(wxEVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATED, wxWebViewEventHandler(MyLoginFrame::OnNavigationComplete), NULL, this);
```

I am using webView for safe login from third party site: Okta: https://www.okta.com/ .
I am giving `redirectUrl` to my webView, then this url tranfers to another Url `www.mymario.com` and from there it goes to `Okta login page`. but this transferring of urls takes some time and sometimes my `WebView` hangs and says not responding. How should I solve this problem. I know normally we create threads to solve such problems but I am not getting how should I create a thread here and avoid hanging of my App.

```
void MyLoginFrame::OnNavigationComplete(wxWebViewEvent& evt)
{

    string url = evt.GetURL();
    dbg.Debug(__FUNCTION__, "Url is: %s", url.c_str());

}
```

Comment: You need to implement an event loop. Easiest way is to display the webview in a modal dialog. When login process has completed, close the dialog.

Comment: How should I use event loop using modal, can you please elaborate or is there any example ?

Comment: Not sure, but try t handle `EVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED` instead of `EVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATED`.